# Download html file

Tags: import, dataset, html

I want to download the data found on the following page and I am unable to do so.

https://resultados.admision.uni.edu.pe/ep1.html

I have already tried all the options I find in Mathematica but I can't find the way to do it. Specifically, I want to download the data found in the table and then convert it to CSV. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
Import["https://resultados.admision.uni.edu.pe/ep1.html", "Elements"]

Import["https://resultados.admision.uni.edu.pe/ep1.html", "Data"]

Import["https://resultados.admision.uni.edu.pe/ep1.html", "FullData"]
```

[image: imagen]

Comment: Something like ``Dataset@GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations@Import["https://resultados.admision.uni.edu.pe/api/ep1.json"]``? (you can remove the `Dataset@` part depending on what you want to do with the data)

Comment: thanks for the answer